# Nested model templating - backbone & underscore

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have got following JSON:

```
var data = [
                {
                    "headline" : "This is headline",
                    "description": "This is description",
                    "icons": [
                        {
                            "url" : "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8356/8404884161_f1d3efe9d6_b.jpg",
                        },
                        {

                            "url" : "http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8349/8167535290_d824c3e7d2_b.jpg"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ];
```

and this template:

```
<script type="text/template" id="items-tpl">
         <h1> <%= headline %> </h1>
         <p> <%= description %> </p>
         <ul>
             <li><%= url %></li>
         </ul>
 </script>
```

What is the best approach to render this in backbone using underscore (or any other method without additional libraries)

Comment: for the data that you have, did you want to render the template you provided twice? one for each icon??

Comment: Headline and description should appear once and then the icon list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for backbone, unless you want to use it for more than your example. Do it like this with underscore.

**Template**

```
<script type="text/template" id="items-tpl">
         <h1> <%= headline %> </h1>
         <p> <%= description %> </p>
         <ul>
             <% for (var i=0; i < icons.length; i++) { %>
             <li><%= icons[i].url %></li>
             <% } %>
         </ul>
 </script>
```

**Html**

```
<div id="renderedModel"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var templateHtml = _.template($("#items-tpl").html(), data[0]);

$("#renderedModel").append(templateHtml);
```

[Working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/eem3m/16/)